# Can I permanently show what time is in Bolivia with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, datetime, time

I would like to show an analog clock based on this code that shows what time I live so that when the user sees us, the following code works fine but shows the user's time. I want you to permanently show what time it is in america / la_paz gm -4 Bolivia;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        var seconds = new Date().getSeconds();
        var sdegree = seconds * 6;
        var srotate = "rotate(" + sdegree + "deg)";

        $("#sec").css({"-moz-transform" : srotate, "-webkit-transform" : srotate});    
    }, 1000);

    setInterval(function() {
        var hours = new Date().getHours();
        var mins = new Date().getMinutes();
        var hdegree = hours * 30 + (mins / 2);
        var hrotate = "rotate(" + hdegree + "deg)";

        $("#hour").css({"-moz-transform" : hrotate, "-webkit-transform" : hrotate});   
    }, 1000);

    setInterval(function() {
        var mins = new Date().getMinutes();
        var mdegree = mins * 6;
        var mrotate = "rotate(" + mdegree + "deg)";

        $("#min").css({"-moz-transform" : mrotate, "-webkit-transform" : mrotate});    
    }, 1000 );
});
```

From a comment:

> The idea is to show a clock so that at the moment of contacting us the
>   user can see what time it is in our country of origin where I live
>   America/La_Paz gm-4

Comment: I don't see a question or a description of the issue you're facing.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString

Comment: Do yourself a favor and get [Moment](https://momentjs.com/) for all of your datetime and timezone needs.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are displaying a ticking clock of some sort, using the current time.  Thus I will assume you meant how to get a human-readable name of the local time zone, to associate with the current time, for display purposes to your user.

There are few ways:

- Extract it from the output of `Date.toString`:

  ```
  var d = new Date();              // Example:
  var s = d.toString();            // "Tue May 14 2019 14:29:05 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)"
  var tz = s.match(/\((.*)\)/)[1]; // "Pacific Daylight Time"
  ```
- Extract it from the output of `Date.toLocaleString` with the `timeZone` option specified:

  ```
  var d = new Date();
  var opts = {timeZoneName: 'long'};           // Example:
  var s1 = d.toLocaleString(undefined, opts);  // "5/14/2019, 2:29:05 PM Pacific Daylight Time"
  var s2 = d.toLocaleString();                 // "5/14/2019, 2:29:05 PM"
  var tz = s1.slice(-s2.length);               // "Pacific Daylight Time"
  ```
- Or if you prefer the short name (usually an abbreviation):

  ```
  var d = new Date();
  var opts = {timeZoneName: 'short'};          // Example:
  var s1 = d.toLocaleString(undefined, opts);  // "5/14/2019, 2:29:05 PM PDT"
  var s2 = d.toLocaleString();                 // "5/14/2019, 2:29:05 PM"
  var tz = s1.slice(-s2.length);               // "PDT"
  ```

The first option is probably the easiest, and has the benefit of simplicity and working in all browsers including really old ones.

On the other hand, if you were asking how to get the IANA time zone identifier for the local time zone, then:

```
Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone  // ex: "America/Los_Angeles"
```

Comment: hello thats correct Matt the script works fine but i need a analog clock tiking for user wiew purposes and i needed to be displated timezone from America/La_paz  showing mi corrent time zone.  please help me to set the time correctly.

Comment: The functions you're calling on the `Date` object are in the local time zone.  So when you say you want it to show the correct time zone - it already will be.  Unless you mean that you want it to show time in the `America/La_Paz` regardless of what the local time zone is?  In that case, you can extract the values you need from `toLocaleString` and specify the `timeZone` parameter in the options.

Comment: The idea is to show a clock so that at the moment of contacting us the user can see what time it is in our country of origin where I live America/La_Paz gm-4 can you correct my current code works fine but shows user navigator time